# Where can @XmlElement be placed?

Tags: jaxb, annotations, setter

I have recently seen this JAXB annotation in a project used on a setter. I know from my own experience that @XmlElement can be used on attributes and getters. I'm not sure if this annotation can and should be used on setters, I googled it and couldn't find a clear answer. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Section "8.9 Property & Field" of the JAXB 2.2 specification (see:  https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr222/index2.html)

> For a property, a given annotation can be applied to either read or
>   write property but not both.

In other words the annotation can be put on either the get or set method.  From my experience the majority of people put the annotation on the get method.

Answer (score 2):

[The code](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/3461152ffe39baf32b8550d47d18d58cdbc139c5/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AbstractInlineAnnotationReaderImpl.java#L76-L77) clearly says it does work on setters:

```
public abstract class AbstractInlineAnnotationReaderImpl<T,C,F,M>
    implements AnnotationReader<T,C,F,M> {
...

    public final <A extends Annotation> A getMethodAnnotation(Class<A> annotation, M getter, M setter, Locatable srcPos) {
        A a1 = getter==null?null:getMethodAnnotation(annotation,getter,srcPos);
        A a2 = setter==null?null:getMethodAnnotation(annotation,setter,srcPos);

        if(a1==null) {
            if(a2==null)
                return null;
            else
                return a2;
        } else {
            if(a2==null)
                return a1;
            else {
                // both are present
                getErrorHandler().error(new IllegalAnnotationException(
                    Messages.DUPLICATE_ANNOTATIONS.format(
                        annotation.getName(), fullName(getter),fullName(setter)),
                    a1, a2 ));
                // recover by ignoring one of them
                return a1;
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

However I also could not find a normative reference for this.

Comment: I have added an answer with the spec reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26259767/383861